# TypeError, 'str' is not callable - Python

Tags: python, typeerror

why does this code return a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

```
import string

def containsAny(stri, set):
    """Check whether 'str' contains ANY of the chars in 'set'"""
    return 1 in [c in stri for c in set]

a = containsAny("acde",list(string.ascii_uppercase()))

print "{}".format(a)
```

Comment: You should rename `set` to something different (e.g. `char_set`/`iterable`/`sequence`/`seq`) to avoid shadowing builtin `set`.

Answer (score 1):

`string.ascii_uppercase` is a string, therefore you get an error when trying to call it by adding the `()`.